# Problem with USB Keyboard and Mouse on Raspberry Pi 4B with Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, raspberrypi, 20.10

I have a mostly successful installation of Ubuntu 20.10 running on Raspberry Pi 4B with 4G memory. Right now I'm having issues with it not responding to keyboard and mouse when coming out of sleep/blanked-screen mode.

Here's what's happening:

- Boot up to graphical login screen -- login, work, logoff -- everything seems to work fine.
- After sitting idle for a while, the screen blanks.
- Moving the mouse or hitting a key reactivates the screen -- I can see the login -- but the mouse cursor doesn't move. Keyboard doesn't work either.
- I am able to ssh to the Pi with no issues and restart the X server.
- Looking at the Xorg log I see:

```
[  2500.111] (EE) event3  - Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 15ms, your system is too slow
[  2508.141] (II) modeset(0): Disabling kernel dirty updates, not required.
[  2508.535] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[  2508.536] (II) event0  - Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub: device removed
[  2508.536] (**) Option "fd" "29"
[  2508.536] (II) event1  - Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub Consumer Control: device removed
[  2508.537] (**) Option "fd" "30"
[  2508.537] (II) event2  - Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub System Control: device removed
[  2508.538] (**) Option "fd" "31"
[  2508.538] (II) event3  - Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: device removed
[  2508.547] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2508.547] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[  2508.624] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2508.624] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[  2508.644] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2508.644] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[  2508.701] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2508.701] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
```

/var/syslog also shows an error:

```
Dec 16 13:27:23 cnc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2097]: libinput error: event1  - Dell Dell USB Keyboard Hub: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 88ms, your system is too slow
```

Here are the currently plugged-in USB devices:

root@cnc:/var/log# lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:558c SanDisk Corp. Extreme Portable SSD
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c00e Logitech, Inc. M-BJ58/M-BJ69 Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 413c:2002 Dell Computer Corp. SK-8125 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:1002 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The keyboard is an old Dell with USB Hub. The Logitech mouse is plugged in to the keyboard. The keyboard is plugged in to a USB 2 port. (I've also tried plugging the mouse directly into the Pi instead of the keyboard hub but get the same results.)

The SSD is the boot drive plugged in to a USB 3 port.

If I immediately login after booting, the system runs fine. Only after it sits idle and the screen goes blank do I encounter problems.

Any ideas? Do I need a more modern keyboard and mouse? Are there settings I can play with? This hardware config runs just fine with Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit). I am just hoping to run a 64-bit OS that I am more familiar with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround (inspired by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460041/xwayland-crashes-frequently)):

Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and change `#WaylandEnable=false` to `WaylandEnable=false`.

I also posted our problem [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1909678) to make sure developers are aware of it.